# Shopify or Javascript Debugging

Tags: javascript, forms, debugging, shopify

## Situation:

- Working on a Shopify theme.
- Using a theme made by other developers - https://themeforest.net/item/kalles-clean-versatile-shopify-theme/26320622
- Making customisation to the current theme.

When running the new module (#c-orderNote if you want to look at the code. Contains all script, css & html used for the module) [image: #c-orderNote module]

It works in my Shopify CLI locally but the moment I move it to the live site it starts throwing this error which is part of the theme script that has nothing to do with the new module that I have made.[image: Error on live site]

[image]

I'm having an issue with a cart form submitting consistently.

Currently this is how [this page is code](https://haverford.com.au/). Either using the cart page OR cart Ajax drawer.

1. I have a input box for customers to select their delivery option.
2. There is a textbox for customers so they can put in their own notes(optional).
3. Javascript is used to combine the options selected(from step 1 and 2) into the hidden textbox(id="CartSpecialInstructions") inside the form that has name="note" which should always submit with the form.

```
   <textarea 
    name="note" 
    id="CartSpecialInstructions" 
    class="t4s-cart-note__input" 
    placeholder="How can we help you?" spellcheck="false">
   </textarea>
```

## Possible solutions:

- What was a good video/blog on How to debug scripts when you have multiple running in tandum?
  OR
- Did you see a reason why the two would be conflicting?

Comment: NO issue occurred on this page as described in the message during the check.

Comment: @Onkar Thank you for checking out the code - I was able to isolate it to the cart drawer specifically. The cart page itself seems to submit reliably. Cart drawer can be found on any page in the top right (except the /cart/ page).